# Using a wildcard to generate output file, not just input file, failing with sh

Tags: shell, unix, sh, io-redirection

Assume this file tree:

```
$PWD
____dir1
________file.one
________file.two
____dir2
________file.one
________file.two
```

I want to replace contents of *file.one* in each directory, with contents of corresponding *file.two* in that same directory.

I use the following code to accomplish this simple task:

```
cat ./*1/*.one > ./*1/*.two
cat ./*2/*.one > ./*2/*.two
```

It works as intended, BUT when I try to execute this like this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'cat ./*1/*.one > ./*1/*.two'

/bin/sh: ./*1/*.two: No such file or directory
```

The following error ^^ occurs.

NOTE: When I use Bash instead of Shell everything works even with -c flag.

Comment: The original code is not guaranteed to work *anywhere*, including on bash; behavior in using a glob rather than a specific filename for the right-hand side of a redirection varies not just between sh and bash, but also between *different releases of bash*, and so shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: BTW, your English-language prose says that you want to replace `file.one` with the contents of `file.two`, but the code you say is working to-spec performs the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is extremely fragile. If you generate your output name from your input file name, and avoid assuming that it already exists (and that there's exactly one match), you're on much firmer ground:

```
set -- ./*1/*.one                 # replace "$@" with list of matches for ./*1/*.one
for arg do                        # this is shorthand for: for arg in "$@"; do
  [ -e "$arg" ] || continue       # ignore files that don't exist (f/e, failed matches)
  cat "$arg" >"${arg%.one}.two"   # use a PE to replace .one with .two in output name
done
```

...which is to say, the following works as-intended on all POSIX-compliant shells:

```
sh -c 'set -- ./*1/*.one; for arg do [ -e "$arg" ] || continue; cat "$arg" >"${arg%.one}.two"; done'
```

See [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for details on the `${arg%.one}` syntax.